# How to set displaymember in code-behind?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

XAML

```
<ComboBox Height="23.338" x:Name="cboCustom" />
```

Code which runs when the combobox should be populate

```
cboCustom.Items.Clear()
For x As Integer = 0 To (_collection.count - 1)
  cboCustom.Items.Add(_collection.node(x))     
Next
```

The _collection.node() is class with several properties
And I would like to set the displayMembervalue of the WPF combobo to it's description property.

I've tried

```
cboCustom.DisplayMemberPath = "myitem.description"
```

and

```
cboCustom.DisplayMemberPath = "description"
```

With no luck.

cboCustom.SeletedItem.description (on select action) does however give me the expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `"Description"` on its own (assuming that's the name of the property you want to display).  Also, make sure the casing is correct.

Comment: I've tried that too, but it still display the names of the collection as empty. If I however in watch type cboCustom.selectedItem.description then it gives me the correct value.

Comment: What happens if you use `cboCustom.ItemsSource = _collection` instead of the code you posted?

Comment: That won't work. Node is a property which returns an instance of a class. That's why I iterate and use Items.Add(..get instance). Maybe I should iterate to a collection and use that as a itemssource

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed that, and I'm not sure whether using `ItemsSource` will make a difference.  I do think you would see a binding error written to the Output window when debugging with your current code, though... is there anything present?

Comment: Thanks!! I did get a binding error which helped me to find the problem. The instance of the class which was returned had not exposed it's member variables as properties. Thanks again!! :)